# dynamically setting the color in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jxl

I wanted to set color of an HTML element using JavaScript. It is okay when i specify it like **ele.style.color="red";** But I wanted to set color something like **ele.style.color=rgb(r,g,b);** where the arguments r,g and b are variables. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ele.style.color = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
```

Comment: Thanks collapsar!! I understood that the color should be given as a string not as a function!!! am i right? When rgb() is an identifier (i mean, a function) why can not it be directly used? why we should use it as a string? When i'm able to call Math.random() directly why can not i call rgb() the same way??

Comment: @PoornaChandraK: don't be fooled by the lexical representation: `rgb` need not be a function. it might just be a lexicalization like `#80cafe` following a different syntax. even if it was a function, it would be a function to the css processor. however, you are not communicating with the css processor in javascript. instead your are _specifying_ what the css processor is supposed to do.